# Use Mathematical Induction to prove 6 divides $n(n+1)(2n+1)$

Tags: induction

By using the principle of Mathematical Induction, prove that: $P(n)=n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is divisible by $6$.

My Attempt:
Base Case: $n=1$
$$P(1)=1(1+1)(2\times 1+1)$$
$$=2\times 3$$
$$=6$$,
Which is divisible by $6$.
$P(1)$ is divisible by $6$

Induction Hypothesis: $(n=k)$
$P(k)=k(k+1)(2k+1)$

Now, how.should I move on?

Comment: With the inductive step, what you do first is assume that whatever you are trying to prove is true for $n=k$, then attempt to use that assumption to show it holds true for $n=k+1$

Comment: Hint: write down $P(k+1)-P(k)$.

Comment: @Dxiv, in which step? And how? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: (Just for interest) Apart from induction, another way to prove it is to consider the formula for the sum of squared natural numbers (Faulhaber formula for $n=2$).

Comment: @Ramanujan, What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induction hypothesis - $P(k): k(k+1)(2k+1)$ is divisible by $6$, i.e. $k(k+1)(2k+1)=6m$ for some $m$.

Now, $$\begin{align} &(k+1)\{(k+1)+1\}\{2(k+1)+1\} \\ = & (k+1)(k+2)(2k+3) \\ = & k(k+1)(2k+3)+2(k+1)(2k+3) \\ = & k(k+1)(2k+1)+2k(k+1)+2(k+1)(2k+3) \\ = & 6m+(k+1)(2k+4k+6) \\ = & 6m+6(k+1)^2 \end{align}$$

So $(k+1)\{(k+1)+1\}\{2(k+1)+1\}$ is divisible by $6$ i.e. $P(k+1)$ is true.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Since by induction hypothesis $P(k)$ is divisible by $6$ then $P(k+1)$ is divisible by $6$ iff the difference $P(k+1)-P(k)$ is divisible by $6$. Now
$$P(k+1)-P(k)=(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)-k(k+1)(2k+1)\\
=(k+1)\left[(k+2)(2k+3)-k(2k+1)\right]=6(k+1)^2.$$

Comment: $P(n)$ is to be divisible by $6$.

Comment: @user354073 Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Is your solution the induction step?

Comment: @user354073 Yes!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: assume by the induction hypothesis that $P(k)$ is divisible by $6$. Then note that:

$$
\begin{align}
P(k+1)-P(k) & =(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)-k(k+1)(2k+1) \\
& = (k+1)(2k^2 + 7k + 6 - 2k^2 - k) \\
& = (k+1)(6k+6) = 6(k+1)^2
\end{align}
$$

is divisible by $6$ as well.

Comment: Why did you.subtract $P(k)$?

Comment: Because if $P(k)$ is a multiple of $6$ (by the induction hypothesis) *and* $P(k+1)-P(k)$ is a multiple of 6 (as proved above), then their sum $P(k+1)$ will be a multiple of $6$ which concludes the induction step.

Comment: $P(k+1)-P(k)$ then, is your induction step?

Comment: That's the intermediate step to prove that $P(k+1)=P(k) + (P(k+1)-P(k))$ is a multiple of $6$ which is technically the induction step.